# Cuda: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000

Tags: c++, c, cuda

My code:

```
int main() {

cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;

FILE *fp2 = fopen("key.txt", "r");
size_t len = 256;
char *line = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);

int icount = 0;
char **m_keyword;
cudaMallocManaged(&m_keyword, len *550000 * sizeof(char *));
while (fgets(line, len, fp2) != NULL) {
    line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';

    err = cudaMallocManaged(&(m_keyword[icount]), sizeof(line) / sizeof(char *) * sizeof(char));

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "(error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    }
    strcpy(m_keyword[icount], line);    // Access violation writing location
    icount++;
}
free(line);

kern_2D << < 55000, 1 >> > (m_keyword, icount);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

return 0;
}
```

I'm writing the code to read text file have content likes this

```
motorcycle ckd
new apsonic
ckd 2017
ckd 2018
motorcycle apsonic
new motorcycle apsonic
```

If I run file have 2000 lines, everything is fine. But if i run over 26000 lines, got a random for error "Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000." Something can run, something got error. 
Please help me.

Comment: `fgets()` null terminates the `line` for you. But more importantly, when calling `cudaMallocManaged()` to allocate memory for `m_keyword[icount]`, using `sizeof(line) / sizeof(char*) * sizeof(char)` is all wrong, you need to use `strlen(line)+1` instead. In fact, even your first call to `cudaMallocManaged()` is wrong, you shouldn't be using `len*`. And you are not stopping your program if `cudaMallocManaged()` ever fails. And you should limit your `while` loop to make sure `icount` doesn't exceed 550000, since that is how many `char*` pointers `m_keyword` can hold

Comment: @RemyLebeau. Thank you for this aws. My file has 50.000 lines. So I think the pointer can hold that. If you have time, can you fix my code? I just writing for cuda.

Comment: "*My file has 50.000 lines*" - then you are allocating WAY more memory than you need for `m_keyword`. "*If you have time, can you fix my code?*" - are you having trouble understanding the 2 simple changes I explained to you?  You are passing the wrong byte sizes to `cudaMallocManaged()` in both cases.

Comment: Curious, who or what text suggested `line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';` to get rid of potential trailing `'\n'`?  IMO, this can cause _Access violation writing location 0_ as it is not known that `strlen(line) > 0`.  Instead code could use `size_t len = strlen(line); if (len && line[len-1] == '\n') line[--len] == '\0';`

Answer (score 1):

When you are calling `cudaMallocManaged()` to allocate memory for `m_keyword[icount]`, you are using `sizeof(line) / sizeof(char*) * sizeof(char)` for the byte length, which is wrong (4 / 4 * 1 = 1 byte!).  You need to use `strlen(line)+1` instead.

In fact, even your first call to `cudaMallocManaged()` is incorrect. You shouldn't be multiplying the number of `char*` pointers by `len` at all.  You are allocating 256 times more bytes than you really need.

That being said, you are not stopping your program at all if `cudaMallocManaged()` (or anything else) fails.  And you should limit your `while` loop to make sure `icount` doesn't exceed the number of `char*` pointers you allocate space for.

Try something more like this instead:

```
int main()
{    
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("key.txt", "r");
    if (!fp2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    const size_t max_lines = 55000; 
    const size_t max_line_len = 256;

    char line[max_line_len];
    size_t line_len;

    char **m_keyword = NULL;
    int icount = 0;

    cudaError_t err = cudaMallocManaged((void**)&m_keyword, max_lines * sizeof(char*));
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory for m_keyword! %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        fclose(fp2);
        return 1;
    }

    do
    {
        if (!fgets(line, max_line_len, fp2))
        {
            if (ferror(fp2) && !feof(fp2))
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from file!\n");
                fclose(fp2);
                return 1;
            }
            break;
        }

        line_len = strlen(line);
        if ((line_len > 0) && (line[line_len - 1] == '\n'))
        {
            line[line_len - 1] = '\0';
            --line_len;
        }

        err = cudaMallocManaged((void**)&(m_keyword[icount]), line_len + 1);
        if (err != cudaSuccess)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory for m_keyword[%d]! %s\n", icount, cudaGetErrorString(err));
            fclose(fp2);
            return 1;
        }

        strcpy(m_keyword[icount], line);
        ++icount;
    }
    while (icount < max_lines);

    fclose(fp2);

    kern_2D << < max_lines, 1 >> > (m_keyword, icount);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Remy Lebeau. Now, i understood your comments.

Comment: @Thinh.Nguyen the original problem was that you were accessing a NULL pointer causing an AV error. The code I have given you avoids that error, and gives you diagnostics when something fails. But your screenshot doesn't show the actual error message being logged, so all I can see is that `cudaMallocManaged()` is failing to allocate 19 bytes of memory after successfully allocating 20000 lines beforehand. My guess is maybe you are running out of available memory? What is `cudaGetErrorString()` reporting exactly?